# Spark MLlib in java does not work

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, dependencies, apache-spark-mllib

My problem is that I have downloaded Apache Spark for java and create a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works fine, but I cannot import MLlib from Apache Spark. I tried for example:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors;
```

But I have a message "Cannot resolve symbol 'ml'". What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add [Apache Spark MLLib dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11/2.3.0) in your maven file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Correct. Then you will find the Vectors class in `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors`, not in `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors`. This has been changed.